# Why is dplyr::filter not working in my function after the update?

Tags: r, dplyr

I wrote a function designed to compute custom confidence intervals on "double distribution" data.

```r
southjetty <- function(uct_df) {
  require(dplyr)
  x1 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(treat == "A") %>%  summarize(x1 = mean(y))
  x2 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(treat == "B") %>%  summarize(x2 = mean(y))
  sd1 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(treat == "A") %>%  summarize(sd1 = sd(y))
  sd2 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(treat == "B") %>%  summarize(sd2 = sd(y))
  num1 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(treat == "A") %>%  summarize(num1 = n())
  num2 <- df %>% dplyr::filter(treat == "B") %>%  summarize(num2 = n())
  sd1s <- (sd1^2)/num1
  sd2s <- (sd2^2)/num1
  diff <- x1 - x2
  srs <- sqrt(sd1s + sd2s)
  me <- srs * 1.96
  upper.ci <- diff + me
  lower.ci <- diff - me
  newlist <- list(diff, lower.ci, upper.ci)
  return(newlist)
}
```

Before the `dplyr` update it worked great. Now it comes up with the following error:  `Error in UseMethod("filter_") :  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "function"`. This is confusing because it seems that I am following the same syntax as used in the new `dplyr` update with `filter` (e.g. the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html)).

Here is the [link](https://github.com/EOneita/surfR/blob/master/uct_test_data_southjetty.csv) to the test dataset that used to work on it. I am using R version 4.0.2 on MacOS Catalina (R Studio Version 1.3.1073).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your input argument is `uct_df` while you are using `df` inside the function.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @akrun it worked previously in that format, but perhaps that could have an effect now? I would think that would throw up an error before filter though, right?

Comment: May be because there is an object 'df' in the global env and now there is not.  You can change the argument of the function to `df` instead of `uct_df` and try

Comment: @akrun you are completely right- changing it to df made it work, which has thrown me, since it worked previously in the different object format! thank you for suggesting that- such a simple fix

Comment: I think the above code can be simplified

Comment: @akrun I agree with you, it is very ugly. I hardly ever write functions (as I'm sure is apparent) so I am still getting to grips with writing things in a simpler form (I'm also still getting to grips with dplyr- I know I have only scratched the surface!).